# python Pandas how to set my custom index combining string and number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe like this:

```
product_nmae
Productashd
productddsf
productkid
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this:

```
  product_nmae    unique_id
    Productashd    sku-1
    productddsf    sku-2
    productkid    sku-3
```

I tried this `df['unique_id'] = df.index + 1` which giving result something like this

```
  product_nmae    unique_id
    Productashd       0
    productddsf       1
    productkid        3
```

how to get my expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create default index and for possible add `sku` convert to strings:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['unique_id'] = 'sku-' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)
```